# I'm trying to get the output pasted in a separate sheet when the condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on 39 stores data where I want to see which NPV is more than 5% by the set target. For this I have started with a 15% (0.15) as my base % on sales and then it gets incremented by 1% every time and it should stop at the place where the 5% target is met and then the data available at that time must be copied into the other sheet. I tried the following code and was struck. A quick help is much appreciated.

```
Sub eightyftmodel_simulation()
    Dim i As Integer, J As Double

    For i = 4 To 42              
        Sheets("Simulation").Range("D2").Value = Sheets("center checks").Cells(i, 30).Value

        For J = 0.15 To 1    
            Sheets("Simulation").Range("D4").Value = J 
            If Range("I6") > 0.05 Then
                'Center Name 
                 Sheets("80ftmodel").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("simulation").Range("D2")

                 'Revshare%     
                 Sheets("80ftmodel").Cells(i, 2).Value = J

                 'ET NPV
                 Sheets("80ftmodel").Cells(i, 3).Value = Sheets("simulation").Range("I2")

                 'MG NPV
                 Sheets("80ftmodel").Cells(i, 4).Value = Sheets("simulation").Range("I3")

                 'Revshare NPV
                 Sheets("80ftmodel").Cells(i, 5).Value = Sheets("simulation").Range("I4")

            Else: J = J + 0.01      
            End If        
        Next J
    Next i    
End Sub
```

Comment: I do not follow what your goal here is. You want to filter store data with NPVs of 5% above the set target? What do you mean by set target? Please simplify your question and I will help you with the code.

Comment: Simulation sheet have the excel model where in these 39 sites will be checked one after the other (using a dropdown) for existing NPV (set target) Vs the new NPV. If new NPV is more than 5% of existing NPV, the particulars in simulation sheet for that center has to be copied to another sheet. Hope this clarifies

Comment: The query must run starting from 0.15 as the Cost of capital input (j) till the output is met (NPV >5% ) by increasing the input by 1% at a time.